# What's the tidiest way to expose a readonly collection in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

How do I define a type that exposes readonly access to a collection that can be manipulated internally by the type itself?

I'm looking for an approach that has the minimum amount of boilerpate.

UPDATE

Thanks for the answers so far, but this should give a clearer idea of what I'm looking for.

```ts
export class Item {
   public Prop1: number;
   public Prop2: string;
}


export class Container {

   public get Items(): ??? {
      // Return something that enables the client to access and modify individual items but _not_ change the contents
      // of the _items array, ideally without just copying the entire array.
   }

   private _items: Item[] = [];
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Give a use case etc

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript can't prevent the developer to update a property of an object.

## The JavaScript way

Maybe with an [ES6 iterable](http://www.zsoltnagy.eu/es6-iterators-and-generators-in-practice/).

Or with an implementation using [ES5 getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

... or maybe a library like [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) could be used?

## The contribution of TypeScript

The typing could be described with the help of the [`readonly` modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#readonly-modifier).

Answer (score 0):

I'm *guessing* that you're looking for something that takes a class you've defined in a module and exports a version of it which doesn't allow write access to its properties at compile-time (as opposed to something that acts at runtime, which TypeScript will not help you with).  If so, you can do something like:

### `private.ts`:

```
// your private class with read-write properties
class Private {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  constructor(n: string) {
    this.name = n;
    this.age = 0;
  }
}

export const Exposed: (new (...args: any[]) => Readonly<Private>) & typeof Private = Private;
export type Exposed = Readonly<Private>;
```

### `consumer.ts`:

```
import { Exposed } from './private'
var x: Exposed = new Exposed('monkey'); 
x.name = 'whoa';  // error, readonly
x.age = 3; // error, readonly
```

That might be enough for you.  If not, please put more details in your question  so we can help further.  Cheers!

Comment: No, the modifier `readonly` is not enough. Here is how to update the name of your instance `x`: `function rename(obj: {name: string}, newName: string) {
    obj.name = newName
}
rename(x, "whoa") // Updated`

Comment: @Paleo Yes, `readonly` is [brittle](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13347), but it might be sufficient for @Neutrino's needs, depending on the use cases.  If something more strict is needed, there are heavier-weight solutions replacing property accesses with methods, where only the "get"-like methods are exposed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReadonlyArray. Check this article https://mariusschulz.com/blog/read-only-array-and-tuple-types-in-typescript or the official documentation https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/32329884)